# Functional Attributes C#

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, aop

In C#, how could you inject code either using an attribute itself or an attribute as a marker for some form reflection?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class AddMessage : Attribute
{
    public AddMessage()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

For example, with `AddMessage` could you manipulate an auto property from something that looks like this

```
[AddMessage]
public int Count { get; set; } = 0;
```

To something that looks like this?

```
private int count;
public int Count {
    get {
        return count;
    }
    set {
        count = value;
        Console.WriteLine("Setter Message");
    }
}

//Somewhere else
count = 0;
```

Comment: You can't do it with attributes, but you can do it with AOP. You would need something like an OnExit aspect http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_onmethodboundaryaspect or OnSetValue http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for the links but I'd quite like to avoid post sharp due to pricing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) framework.  Its general approach is to modify your assembly after it's compiled ("weaving") based on what's found in there.  I don't love that it's all "meta" rather than being part of the code itself, but it can do things that are otherwise impossible.

The [Anotar](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar) module looks along the lines of what you want to do, or else you might write your own module.